# Ask for externally_connectable using optional_permissions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have extension with few permissions:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
```

For adding a new feature, we need to add `externally_connectable` permssion, should be like:

```
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
  },
```

All seem to work perfectly locally, but if we upload this change to Chrome Store, the extension will be disabled and show the "New Permissions" warning, i tested that with custom update url and unfortunately that happen.

Is there any way to ask for this permission on runtime using `optional_permissions` and `chrome.permissions.request`?

Edit:

Running:

```
chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: ['externally_connectable'],
    origins: ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}, function(granted) {
    console.log('permision:', granted);
});
```

Return this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running permissions.request: 
    'externally_connectable' is not a recognized permission.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [chrome.permissions API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#manifest) and [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/permissions/extensions_api_permissions.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1471534131&l=109), `externally_connectable` cannot be optional.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, i wonder if we can get around it using [this one](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/permissions/extensions_api_permissions.cc?rcl=1471534131&l=67), code review [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/599163003/)

Comment: That one won't help, it just allows `<all_urls>` for a pattern in a [couple of whitelisted extensions](https://codereview.chromium.org/599163003/diff/20001/extensions/common/api/_permission_features.json).